# Post UIKeyboardDidShowNotification manually

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

Because the keyboard hides the textfields when coming up I implemented [a solution](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-keeping-content-from-underneath-the-keyboard--mobile-6103) for this. Now I also have built in the possibility that the user taps on the next button of the keyboard and directly jumps to the next textfield (tabbing between fields).

The problem now is that the view doesn't scroll if I use `becomeFirstResponder` only. The keyboard is up but the `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` is not triggered and so the view doesn't slide up.

Can I fake such a notification so that the `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` is sent by the notification center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use two great libraries for this. [BSKeyboardControls](https://github.com/simonbs/BSKeyboardControls) for the tabbing and [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) for moving the view.

If you just want to send the notification my guess is that `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:self]` should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the libraries. The thing is that I'd need a Monotouch port for this ... I tried to send the notification as you posted, but I needed to create a notification. This notification should be the same like the one from the OS. And I don't know how to do that. `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` is NSString in Monotouch. How do you create the notification here?

Comment: Now the notification is fired. In my method `keyboardWasShown` I need the `userInfo` object to get the keyboard size. Manually posting the notification causes `userInfo` to be `nil`. What's the cause for this? What can I do against this to get my keyboard size?

Comment: That's a tricky question. Perhaps save the sizes the first time the keyboard appears? So check if `userInfo` is `nil`, if not, save the sizes, if it is, use the stored sizes instead. That way it will save it the first time the keyboard appears and recall it when you manually post the notification.

Comment: OK, that would be a workaround. Thanks for your thoughts. You also have to be aware if orientation has changed in the meantime and switch out the values (height/width) if needed. But if you do that your approach could work if the keyboard was opened before (for my case it's true because there is a textfield before and this one needs scrolling right at the beginning). But for now I'll stay with my solution. I give you the credits because it answers my question more directly.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple:

1. `resignFirstResponder`
2. `becomeFirstResponder`

I can only provide the solution for C# (that's why I left it out first):

```
private bool TextFieldShouldReturn (UITextField textfield)
{
    if (textfield.Tag == 1) {
        UIResponder nextResponder = this.View.ViewWithTag (2);
        textfield.ResignFirstResponder ();
        nextResponder.BecomeFirstResponder ();
    } else if(textfield.Tag == 2){
        textfield.ResignFirstResponder ();
        loginButton.SendActionForControlEvents (UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside);
    } else {
        // Not found, so remove keyboard.
        textfield.ResignFirstResponder ();
    }

    return false; // We do not want UITextField to insert line-breaks.
}
```

I set some tags on each textfield. Than I use the delegate `usernameText.ShouldReturn += TextFieldShouldReturn;` to call my method `TextFieldShouldReturn`. This method selects the next textfield. To jump to the next text field you first dismiss the keyboard with `resignFirstResponder` and present the keyboard with `becomeFirstResponder`. With this code the `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` is called like the user would tap on the textfield (= simulated tap).

Comment: You need to add some explanation on how to use these points. At least post an example on how to use these notifications.

Comment: I updated my answer. For me it was clear how you use that code. Now I added more code (though in C#) which shows how to use the posted solution.

Comment: Your answer was flagged as low quality. It is quite complete in itself now.